# best practices for chaining promises without return values

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

Long short - I have about 4 or 5 different functions running in one promise on an express server.  Large data sets are making me hit a timeout on Heroku so I'm trying to break it into different steps.  The promises don't return anything but only update files on the server asynchronously.

Question is what is the best practice to trigger the resolve of the promises?  Right now I'm just sending undefined as they weren't getting triggered but I'm curious what the best practices are.

running express server with node backend

```
app.post("/pdf", (req, res) => {
res.contentType("application/json");
req.body.layout.callsheet ?

toPNG.pdfToPNG(req.body.layout.callsheet, pdfPath)
  .then( async () => {
  
  await generatePDf(req.body.data, pdfPath, req.body.layout.selected)
    .then(() => {

      console.log()
      layout === "landscape" ?
      
        call.doubleCover(`${pdfPath}`, `${pdfPath}-coverSheet.png`)
          .then(res.send(undefined)) :   // <---------- is there a better way to do this?

        call.singleCover(`${pdfPath}`, `${pdfPath}-coverSheet.png`)
          .then(res.send(undefined)).    // <---------- is there a better way to do this?

    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err + " line 151"))

}) : generatePDf(req.body.data, callSheet)
   .then(res.send(undefined))   // <---------- is there a better way to do this?

.catch(err => res.send(err + " line 162"))
```

})

Comment: You don't need `.then()` in `await fn().then()`. You just need `await fn();` That's the main benefit of using `await`.

Comment: Your current approach won't work as desired, pretty sure. `.then(res.send(undefined))` should at least be `.then(() => res.send(undefined))` etc

Comment: good eye - I've only been working with one side of that ternary

Comment: If you want to just send a response and THEN finish your work on the server (to avoid hitting a client or Heroku timeout), then just do `res.send("received")` or `res.json({status: "ok"})` once and then finish your processing on the server.  The Heroku timeout is ONLY about the outgoing response to the incoming HTTP response.  Your server is free to continue processing until it finishes independent of the http timeout.  And, you only send ONE `res.send()` per request.  All others will be ignored by Express.  You could do multiple `res.write()` followed by one final `res.end()`.

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean by "*trigger the resolve of the promises*". Also, the best practice to have each promise fulfill with a proper value, not `undefined` - are your operations not doing anything, do they not have a result?

Comment: This is not a question about "best practice", since the code is clearly calling `res.send` at the wrong moment. You should rephrase your question, removing all that "best practice" and explain the problem you currently have.

Comment: where should I put my res.send()?